# EAV Set Data into Set Based Aggreate Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, aggregate

I have data that is generated when a user logs into the application.  It contains a timestamped login and logout, which are not attributed to any specific work campaign.  Those are my boundaries for each record.

Within that time frame, I have repeatable actions, Task 1, Task2, Break, etc, which are attributed to a campaign.

In order to start working on another campaign a user must log off and back on the application, which would start the process over again.

In this fiddle, I have laid out the table and sample data, and my first attempt to gather the data, but with this approach the start and stop time from the login/logouts are summed together, but I need the data to reflect the start and stop time for the campaign, which I am at a lose on how to do.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5347c/1

My results need to include:

- Campaign
- Originator
- Start (time from login action for that set)
- End (time from logout action for that set)
- Sum of Task 1 for the set
- Sum of Task 2 for the set
- Last Task for that Set

  ```
  ══════════════════════════════════════════════════
  Campaign Originator Start End   Task1 Task2 LastAction
  ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
  Camp1    1000       08:00 09:27 3120  855    Logout   
  Camp2    1000       09:30 10:32 1800  135    Logout   
  Camp1    1000       13:00 0        0         Task1
  ```

I've tried a CTE approach to get the Login and Logout times as individual row, but then I worked myself into a circle of confusion as I wasn't sure of the next step.

Can someone please share an idea of how I could achieve these results give this data?

Comment: Can you edit your post and show what you want for the desired result? Instead of a bulleted list.

Comment: Try that, table layouts here leave much to be desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably needs some refactoring:

```
;with Sessions as (
    select OriginatorId, State, Duration, ActionLocalTime, Campaign
        -- Get an id that will later be used to find the max row per session. Break ties with logical State order.
        , row_number() over (order by OriginatorId, ActionLocalTime, case State when 'Login' then 10 when 'Logout' then 30 else 20 end, State) as RowNum
        -- Get a Session id for each login
        , (select count(*) from Actions where State = 'Login' and OriginatorID = a.OriginatorID and ActionLocalTime <= a.ActionLocalTime) as Session
    from Actions a
), Campaigns as (
    select OriginatorId, State, Duration, ActionLocalTime, RowNum
        -- Get the Campaign for this session
        , (select max(Campaign) from Sessions where OriginatorID = s.OriginatorID and Session = s.Session) as Campaign
    from Sessions s
)
select Campaign
    , OriginatorID as Originator
    , min(ActionLocalTime) as Start
    , (select ActionLocalTime from Sessions where RowNum = max(c.RowNum) and State = 'Logout') as [End]
    , (select sum(Duration) from Campaigns where OriginatorID = c.OriginatorID and Campaign = c.Campaign and State = 'Task 1') as Task1
    , (select sum(Duration) from Campaigns where OriginatorID = c.OriginatorID and Campaign = c.Campaign and State = 'Task 2') as Task2
    , (select State from Sessions where RowNum = max(c.RowNum)) as LastAction
from Campaigns c
group by OriginatorID, Campaign
order by OriginatorID, Campaign
```

Output:

```
Campaign Originator Start                   End                     Task1 Task2 LastAction
-------- ---------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----- ----- ----------
Camp1    1000       2013-05-06 08:00:00.000 2013-05-06 09:27:00.000 3120  855   Logout
Camp2    1000       2013-05-06 09:30:00.000 2013-05-06 10:32:00.000 1800  135   Logout
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc1ee/1) with a little extra data.

Comment: Initial test seem to confirm that this is a awesome.   Running it on several million row records and its coming together nicely!!!

Comment: Cool, glad to hear. It could probably use some optimization, and may have some edge cases that aren't accounted for.

Comment: I was looking more for direction than exact working, so you went above and beyond.  This is similar to the CTE I had written on my first attempt, I can definitely tune and put in the more specific requirements.  Thanks.

Comment: On the last query, where we gather the task time for each campaign, it is gathering the time for every single entry of that campaign, not the set of that campaign.  Thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you possibly create a SQL Fiddle with offending data and describe how it is incorrect?

Comment: I'm having a problem making it show the problem, but let me clarify the question:   On this part:  (select sum(Duration) from Campaigns where OriginatorID = c.OriginatorID and Campaign = c.Campaign and State = 'Task 2',   how does it limit those queries to the specific session?

Comment: Disregard, I found my problem.